# HTTP Status 500 - An exception occurred processing JSP page /login.jsp at line 6. (error message title)

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, tomcat7

I really need some one to  rescue me. I'm so grateful for last time, I posted a problem. Unfortunately the same problem / similar problem still pops up for almost 2 months. I can't finish up my projects because of 'this driver problem'.  I installed a couple of J/Connectors but still received an HTTP error message. So I decided to use MySQL installer to install all components  and this time receive this error message below:

```
HTTP Status 500 - An exception occurred processing JSP page /login.jsp at line 6
type Exception report

message An exception occurred processing JSP page /login.jsp at line 6

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this.

exception 
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /login.jsp at line 6

3: <%
4:  String userid = request.getParameter("uname");
5:  String pwd = request.getParameter("pass");
6:  Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
7:  Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection
8:  ("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/REG",
9:      "root", "$jademedia247");


Stacktrace:
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:568)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:455)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)



root cause 
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:912)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:841)
org.apache.jsp.login_jsp._jspService(login_jsp.java:93)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)



root cause 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1702)
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1547)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:126)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:63)
java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169)
org.apache.jsp.login_jsp._jspService(login_jsp.java:72)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)



note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.50 logs.


Apache Tomcat/7.0.50'
```

**CLASSPATH:C:\Program Files\MySQL\Connector J 5.1.28\mysql-connector-java-5.1.28-bin.jar;C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\lib\jsp-api.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_38\jre\lib**

PATH:C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_38\bin;C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\bin;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Utilities 1.3.6\

**login.jsp**

```
<%@ page import="java.io.*,java.util.*,java.sql.*" %>
<%@ page import="javax.servlet.http.*,javax.servlet.*"%>
<%
    String userid = request.getParameter("uname");
    String pwd = request.getParameter("pass");
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection
    ("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/REG",
        "root", "$jademedia247");
    Statement st = con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs;
    rs = st.executeQuery("select * from members where uname='" + userid + "' and pass='" + pwd + "'");
    if (rs.next()) {
    session.setAttribute("userid", userid);
    //out.println("Welcome" + userid);
    //out.println("<a href='logout.jsp'>Log out</a>");
    response.sendRedirect("Success.jsp");
    } else {
        out.println("Invalid password <a href='form.jsp'> try again </a>");
    }
    %>
```

**registration.jsp**

```
<%@page import ="java.sql.*"%>
<%
user = request.getParameter("uname");
String pwd = request.getParameter("pass");
String fname = request.getParameter("fname");
String lname = request.getParameter("lname");
String email = request.getParameter("email");
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection
("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/REG","root", "$jademedia247");
Statement st = con.createStatement();
//ResultSet rs;
int i = st.executeUpdate("insert into members (first_Name, last_Name, email, uname, pass,     regdate) values ('" + fname + "', '" + lname + "', '" + email + "','" + user + "', '" + pwd + "', CURDATE())"); 
    if (i > 0) {
        //session.setAttribute("userid", user);
        response.sendRedirect("welcome.jsp");
        //out.print("Registration Successfull!"+"<a href='form.jsp'>Go to Login</a>");
    } else {
        response.sendRedirect("form.jsp");
    }
    %>
```

**File Path: C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\webapps\ROOT**

```
CREATE TABLE `members` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `first_name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `uname` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `pass` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `regdate` date NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

**Just created a database REG.**

Comment: well it is not finding the driver class; wrap your classpath entries with a " (because they have spaces) and retry

Comment: BTW, does mysql-connector-java-5.1.28-bin.jar contain "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"?

Comment: @ roberman, this is how I have updated the CLASSPATH:"C:\Program Files\MySQL\Connector J 5.1.28\mysql-connector-java-5.1.28-bin.jar""C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\lib\jsp-api.jar""C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_38\jre\lib"

Comment: and this is what I get, HTTP Status 500 - javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

type Exception report

message javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

Comment: I'm using an Intel Atom - Note Book. When I check for example the j/connector there are no . jar on the files. All the classes or files are diplayed in their respective folders minus the .jar extension, why?

Comment: BTW I don't know how to check for com.mysql.jdbc.Driver in the bin.jar file.

Comment: Open with a zip reader and check it

Comment: @ robermann thanx let me try.

Comment: @robermann , I checked, the com.mysql.jdbc.Driver.java is available.

Comment: Ok, put that jar inside tomacat_dir/lib, and restart it. It should work

Comment: Hey robberman, thanx a million times, u' r' a real genius. As soon as cut & pasted the jar file in lib , there it went, I'm so grateful.

Comment: How can I vote for your answer to increase your reputation ?

Answer (score 3):

Put the file **mysql-connector-java-5.1.28-bin.jar** inside `tomcat_dir/lib/`.